# Is it possible for a variable to be recompiled every time through the For-Loop in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a set of variables that I want to be re-evaluated everytime through the for-loop. Reasoning, is these variables will change (from true to false) for example. However, it doesn't seem that they are being re-evaluated, but only compiled the first time through. This is an example of some variables that I want to be compiled every iteration.

```
For($i = 0; $i -lt 4; $i++) {

$IsPathEmpty = (Get-ChildItem -Path $NewFolderPath | Measure-Object).Count - 
eq 0
$OldFolderPathFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $OldFolderPath 
$NewFolderPathFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $NewFolderPath 
$AreFilesDifferent = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $OldFolderPathFiles - 
DifferenceObject $NewFolderPathFiles 
$BCompare = Get-Process -Name "BCompare" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
#$noDiffs = '' -eq ((Get-Content -Raw C:\bcreport\report.txt) -split '\r?\n- 
+\r?\n')[1].Trim()
$noBCReport = Test-Path -Path "C:\B\report.txt" 

if ($noBCReport -eq $true) {

    $noDiffs = '' -eq ((Get-Content -Raw C:\bcreport\report.txt) -split '\r? 
 \n-+\r?\n')[1].Trim()

}

if ($IsPathEmpty -eq $true -or $AreFilesDifferent -ne $null) {

Robocopy $OldFolderPath $NewFolderPath *.* /E /COPY:DATS /DCOPY:T /purge 
/MT:32 /R:2 /W:5 /LOG:$RoboLog


#HAD TO REMOVE ROBOCOPY USERNAME INFORMATION 

$SetPermissions

} elseif($noBCReport -eq $false -and $BCompareNumber -lt 1) {
   # &"C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4\BCompare.exe" $OldFolderPath 
$NewFolderPath
   mkdir -Path C:\scripts
   New-Item C:\scripts\script.txt 
   Set-Content C:\scripts\script.txt 'load "%1" "%2"
    expand all
    folder-report layout:side-by-side options:display-mismatches output- 
 to:"%3"'

    &"C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 
4\BCompare.exe"`@"C:\scripts\script.txt" $OldFolderPath $NewFolderPath 
"C:\bcreport\report.txt"

    $noDiffs = '' -eq ((Get-Content -Raw C:\bcreport\report.txt -ErrorAction 
    SilentlyContinue) -split '\r?\n-+\r?\n')[1].Trim()
    $noBCReport = Test-Path -Path "C:\BCReport\report.txt"
    $BCompareNumber = 2
} 
  elseif($noDiffs -eq $true -and $DiffNumber -lt 1 ) {
    Remove-SMBShareAndDeleteFolder -ShareName $ShareName
    Add-NewSharePath -ShareName $ShareName
    $DiffNumber = 2
} elseif($noDiffs -eq $false -and $NewDiffNumber -lt 1) {
    &"C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4\BCompare.exe" $OldFolderPath $NewFolderPath
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('There were differences in files. Check Beyond Compare for results.')
    $NewDiffNumber = 2
   }
 }  
}
```

Specifically, the noBCReport variable will change from false to true after the second pass through the for loop. At that point, $noDiffs will also no longer be null. Then, based on the results of $noDiffs the script will continue the for-loop. However, since the $noBCReport variable never gets re-evaluated, it always shows false and the $noDiffs is always null. Any ideas?

Comment: would you please change `recompile` to `re-evaluate`? at no point in your code is any variable being _compiled_ ... and that makes reading your Question quite confusing. [*grin*]

Comment: There's nothing in the code you've shown that writes to `C:\bcreport\report.txt`, so why do you expect it to suddenly exist?

Comment: you create a variable `$AreFilesDifferent` which is never used afterwards. Also `$BCompare` is set to the process if it is running but I assume you want to run BCompare to check for differences and thus you might wanna use `Start-Process` instead?

Comment: This is just a snippet of the variables. These variables are used afterwards. See edited post.